# Is there in Ruby TestUnit a feature analogous to RSpec's shared_examples_for

Tags: ruby, rspec, code-reuse, testunit

I have several implementations of the same interface in Ruby. And I want to test them with the same set of test cases (just parametrize them with the implementation class or instance). How can I do that?